# Reset Password in React

Tags: reactjs

i am creating a mern app. i got stuck in forgot password. i'm able to send a mail for forgot password but when i try to set new password it is not changing password but in postman i was able to change the password but when it comes to react i was not. I know the problem is that i was not able to get token as params .

work in postman but not in when i try in react.

Resetpassword component

```
  import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert';
    import { reset } from '../../actions/auth';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    const Reset = ({ setAlert, reset }) => {
      const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        password: '',
        password2: ''
      });
      const { password, password2 } = formData;
      const onChange = e =>
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      const onSubmit = async => {
        const token = props.match.params.token;
        console.log(token);
        if (password !== password2) {
          setAlert('password does not matched', 'danger');
        } else {
          reset({ password, token });
      }
      };

      return (
        <Fragment>
          <section className='container'>
            <h1 className='large text-primary'>RESET PASSWORD</h1>
            <p className='lead'>
              <i className='fas fa-user' /> Create Your NEW PASSWORD
            </p>
            <form
              className='form'
              onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}
              action='create-profile.html'
            >
              <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type='password'
                  placeholder='Password'
                  name='password'
                  value={password}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type='password'
                  placeholder='Confirm Password'
                  name='password2'
                  value={password2}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
              </div>
              <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' value='Register' />
            </form>
            <p className='my-1'>
              Already have an account? <Link to='/login'>Sign In</Link>
            </p>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
    Reset.propTypes = {
      setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      reset: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    export default connect(
      null,
      { setAlert, reset }
    )(Reset);

resetaction.JS
export const reset = ({ password, token }) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({ password, token });
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/reset/${token}`,
      body,
      config
    );
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_PASSWORD,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By only seeing this snippet I assume your problems are following lines:

```js
const Reset = ({ setAlert, reset }) => {
//...
const token = props.match.params.token;
```

You destructed the whole `props` argument (into `{ setAlert, reset }`), so in your case `props` is `undefined`. You should adapt your code to this:

```js
const Reset = ({ setAlert, reset, match }) => {
//...
const token = match.params.tok
```